# how to mark button active onclick in form element

Tags: javascript, css, forms

How can make the input button active with Onclick?

```
<div class="paForm-right">
    <form onsubmit="" name="form1" id="form1" method="post">
        <input type="submit" class="paForm-choose" id="paForm-bottom-vk" value="Visitenkarten" name="submit" />
        <input type="submit" class="paForm-choose" id="paForm-bottom-briefbogen" value="Briefbogen" name="submit" />
        <input type="submit" class="paForm-choose" id="paForm-bottom-flyer" value="Flyer" name="submit" />
        <input type="submit" class="paForm-choose" id="paForm-bottom-faltblaetter" value="Faltblätter" name="submit" />
        <input type="submit" class="paForm-choose" id="paForm-bottom-einzelblaetter" value="Einzelblätter" name="submit" />
        <input type="submit" class="paForm-choose" id="paForm-bottom-plakate" value="Plakate" name="submit" />
        <input type="submit" class="paForm-choose" id="paForm-bottom-postkarten" value="Postkarten" name="submit" />
        <input type="submit" class="paForm-choose" id="paForm-bottom-prospekte" value="Prospekte" name="submit" />
        <input type="submit" class="paForm-choose" id="paForm-bottom-kataloge" value="Broschüren usw." name="submit" />
        <input type="submit" class="paForm-choose" id="paForm-bottom-mappe" value="Mappe" name="submit" />
        <input type="submit" class="paForm-choose" id="paForm-bottom-buch" value="Bücher" name="submit" />
        <input type="submit" class="paForm-choose" id="paForm-bottom-calender" value="Kalender" name="submit" />
        <input type="hidden" name="value[Produkt]" id="senden" value="Detailanfrage" />
    </form>
    <br />
</div>
```

this is my CSS... but the active background do not work...

```
    input.paForm-choose:hover 
background-color:#D10C2D;


#paForm-bottom-vk 
background-image:url(../Icon_Visitenkarte_HG-Trans.png);

#paForm-bottom-vk:hover 
background-image:url(../Icon_Visitenkarte_HG-Trans.png);


#paForm-bottom-vk:active 
background-image:url(../Icon_Visitenkarte_HG-active.png);
```

Comment: Looks like you really want to have a `<select>` with options and enjoy the benefits of one submit button?

Comment: The solution is a little speciale, the Input forms loock in frontend like Buttons and have diffrent tasks in diffrent forms...

Comment: On gallery for example the button matrix thats base on the same css  works as links for the diffrent sliders:                              <input type="submit" class="paForm-choose" id="paForm-bottom-einzelblaetter" value="Einzelblätter" onClick="self.location.href='/produkte/einzelblaetter' "/>      ...

Comment: and at diffrent contact-forms the inputs calls an special produkt-spezific form thats based on php and load on the same page...  and for this selection i would make the button active after Onclick...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eF9Za/) using your code, with the exception of the fact that I put a "#" in front of your line with the :active on it.

The :active only shows when the key is pressed, not when it is released. So you can see Mickey Mouse when you press and hold the key.

If you what to have it changed until a different key is pressed you'll have to change the js code.

CSS

```
#paForm-bottom-vk:active {
background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/1Xm81k2.jpg');
}
```

Comment: the hover color shoud displayed after leave the key... how could show the js code ?

Comment: But doesn't clicking a button take you to a new page?

Comment: In any case, here is a fiddle that does what you want - http://jsfiddle.net/ML39a/.

Comment: clicking a button load the special produkt form in the individual inquiry..., in the short inquiry php gives out the Produktname and also load the form in same page

Comment: your js code looks fine, i try to modifid for my input elements Thank you very much...